# Hide Text Sent via Post Activity Event

Tags: reactjs, botframework

I'm currently sending a text programmatically to my bot following the article on https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event

Everything is working fine but I want to hide the text being sent so that the user does not see it on the session. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initializing and using the `useSendMessage` hook, replace it with [useSendPostBack](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/HOOKS.md#usesendpostback). Using `useSendPostBack` will generate a `postBack` message activity which simply sends a value back to the bot without displaying it to the user. The value sent to the bot should be located in the `value` property of the associated activity.

```js
const sendPostBack = useSendPostBack();

const handleHelpButtonClick = useCallback(() => sendPostBack('help'), [sendMessage]);
```

A complete list of available hooks can be reviewed in the Web Chat repo doc, [hooks](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/HOOKS.md).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.